# forEach not changing values of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, foreach, internationalization

```
availableButtons.forEach(function(part, index) {
    console.log(this[index].title)
    // this[index].title = intl.formatMessage(this[index].title);
  }, availableButtons)
```

The code above prints the console as follows:

```
{id: "abc.btn.xyz", defaultMessage: "someMessage"}
```

This confirms that each object has an id but when I try to execute the commented code it throws an error saying  `[@formatjs/intl] An id must be provided to format a message.`

I used the same array but only a single object separately as follows `intl.formatMessage(availableButtons[0].title);` this gave me the required result I am just not able to figure out. I tried various ways of passing values in forEach, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a [mre] of your issue so that we can help debug?

Comment: What is the package you are using for `intl`?

Comment: Why are you passing the array you are iterating over as the `thisArg` when `this[index]` is just `part`? You probably also don't want to mutate the array as you are iterating over it. If you are attempting to augment or change the elements in the array you should really use `array.prototype.map` and map into a new array reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `Array#map` works better for in this vade

```js
availableButtons.map(part => {
    return {
    ...part,
    title: intl.formatMessage(part.title)
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

forEach does not actually mutate arrays. it's just a shorthand loop called on the array. It's hard to suggest a solution because your intent is not clear.

```
availableButtons = availableButtons.map(button => {
 //do your mutations here
}
```

might be a start

Answer (score 0):

Access the array (availableButtons) directly and update (mutate) with forEach.

```
availableButtons.forEach(function (part, index) {
  console.log("before: ", availableButtons[index].title);
  availableButtons[index].title = intl.formatMessage(this[index].title);
  console.log("after: ", availableButtons[index].title);
});
```